# Missing required parameters for Route: dashboard URI: dashboard/{id} in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have to add a device for the same user in laravel. I make a user login with user ID but I get this error message

> Missing required parameters for [Route: dashboard] [URI:
>   dashboard/{id}]. (View:
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\addspy\resources\views\frontend\layouts\dashboard-sidebar.blade

My Route is:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{id}', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

please guide me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you call that route? The error message literally says what is wrong

Comment: Show us the code in `dashboard-sidebar.blade` that *uses* the route.

Comment: It means when you call `route('dashboard', auth()->id())` you're missing `auth()->id()` or `auth()->id()` is `null`

Comment: please suggest me I have to add multiple devices in one and no idea about it...https://demo.xnspy.com/my-devices/#_ga=2.153011440.81408126.1583153801-1857282156.1583153801...I have to do like this

Comment: fyi, you can `Edit` your question and paste relevant code here

Comment: Proving the URL will not help us. Please provide the code where you get the error. Looks in your log files may help you.

Comment: I have to allow the different dashboards to a single user for multiple devices. Like - for device1 different dashboard for device2 different dashboard but the user is the same what I do in that case???

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about the question but you can do route parameter optional:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{id?}', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

If your dashboard route not found `id` then you need to handle manually and open default dashboard.

Comment: thanks for your answer...I have to allow the different dashboards to a single user for multiple devices. Like  - for device1 different dashboard for device2 different dashboard but the user is the same...please guide me

Answer (score 0):

We need more than what you show us to assist you better.

Anyway, if you expect `id` parameter of dashboard route to be null, then you need to make it optional in `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard/{id?}', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Remove the `?` if not.

Then add route's parameter to `DashboardController@index` action

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        dd($id);
        // return view(..)
    }
}
```

Finally call the route in `dashboard-sidebar.blade.php`:

```php
route('dashboard', auth()->user()->id)
```